# How to set borders to specific cells in array or align environment, using LyX

Tags: align, lyx, arrays, border, alignat

I was wondering if there's any possible way to set borders to specific cells in an `array` environment **using LyX**? I want to get something like this:

[image: goal]

But all I was able to do without getting dirty with code is:

[image: partial result]

I know it possible to achieve the desired result by writing latex code, but I really want to avoid that. Do you have any idea or workaround? I hope there's a hidden way of creating such matrix using LyX alone. The solution doesn't necessarily have to be based on `array` environment. It may use `align`, `alignat`, etc.

By the way, here is an example of a way one can to this by typing LaTeX (found it in a related thread):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\[
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{array}{*2r @{\hskip\arraycolsep}c@{\hskip\arraycolsep} *4r}
  &    &&    &  1 &  1 & 0 \\
\cline{3-7}
1 & -1 &\multicolumn{1}{|r}{}& 1 &  0 & -1 & 1 \\
  &    &&  1 & -1 \\
\cline{4-6}
  &    &&    &  1 & -1 \\
  &    &&    &  1 & -1 \\
\cline{5-7}
  &    &&    &    &    & 1 \\
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: If it is impossible, where can I file a feature request?
Also, are there any workarounds available?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it in LyX, but to make a feature request you can do so at http://www.lyx.org/trac